# Add a new data type to Pentaho Kettle

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to add a new data type (Geometry) to Kettle. I have added a new Value type to org.pentaho.di.compatibility. I have added a ValueGeometry class and made the necessary modifications to ValueInterface and Value. The code compiles but the new data type does not show up in plugins like Select. What am I missing here? Also I'd appreciate if you could point me towards the source code for these plugins.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Kettle 5.0, it is possible to create a plugin to provide new Value types:
http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-191

I have a plugin to add a key/value type (like java.util.Map):
https://github.com/mattyb149/pdi-valuemeta-map

and another to represent a Graph (using a property graph model):
https://github.com/mattyb149/pdi-graph-computing/tree/master/pdi-valuemeta-graphSON

Both of these are in the PDI Marketplace if you'd like to try them out :)

Comment: I was able to make the data type available at runtime but here's what I want to do now. This datatype will be used by several steps and I need access to it from ValueMeta to write the code for the *Meta.class of each step. Ofcourse including the same plugin in each step wouldn't be a good idea. Any suggestions on that? Thanks.

Comment: @AbhishekDeyDas did you add a geometry type capable to be interoperable with PostGis? where did you get the main class? I believe you have to add one similar to the others. something like `[org.pentaho.di.core.row.value.ValueMetaGeometry]`.