# Access added Kettle data type from the source of a step

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

Following the answer on my previous question ([Add a new data type to Pentaho Kettle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410048/add-a-new-data-type-to-pentaho-kettle/27424762#27424762)), I added a plugin with a custom datatype. Now I have a step where I need to access this custom data type from ValueMeta as in ValueMeta.TYPE_CUSTOMTYPE for the getFields() method. I can't get that to work. Your ideas would be appreciated.

PS: I cannot have the code for the custom DT in the step code as the same DT would be used by several steps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at ValueMetaFactory, there are methods in there to retrieve ValueMeta types by name or integer type:

https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/blob/master/core/src/org/pentaho/di/core/row/value/ValueMetaFactory.java#L133