# Kettle: How to add a geometry type

Tags: geometry, postgis, kettle, geokettle

i'm using kettle but i don't have geometry type. My issue is how can i create a geometry type so i can make transformations with databases that has postgis. I tried to use geokettle but i found some bugs and since that geokettle doesn't have any changes neither forum activity since 2014. I'm having some doubts using geokettle. For that reason i changed to kettle.

I want to ask if somehow is possible to add a geometry type directly in kettle last release (version 6)? And how can i do that?

I would like to know what  steps should i consider or/and which documentation (if exists) should i read to accomplish this task.

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a new data type to Pentaho Kettle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410048/add-a-new-data-type-to-pentaho-kettle)

Comment: Voted to close because this is an exact duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410048/add-a-new-data-type-to-pentaho-kettle  Yes - geokettle seems to be dead - they had the option of porting all their customisations to plugins so that you could have the best of both worlds but they didnt want to do that.

Comment: I agree that this is a two diferent questions with the same title for that reason i will modified the title. In [Add a  new data type to Pentaho Kettle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410048/add-a-new-data-type-to-pentaho-kettle ) has already a geometry class made and his doubt is more about an issue during the process of adding a new value type. i'm asking about "How can i add geometry type" not a "Issue Adding a geometry type" since that the author passed already from a few important steps.

Comment: Maybe for who knows already the answer or are familiar with pentaho source code those links could be the answer. I already install the plugin and it makes sense to use it when you have already a geometry class made, but the question remains how do you add a geometry type (first you need to create that class) How do you do that according to Pentaho structure code... this is a step already made and not explained but it doesn't seem to be a easy task. Sorry, but for me is not so obvious and for that reason is why i ask "How to do it".