# Pentaho Kettle - Convert hex to Number from field of type binary

Tags: binaryfiles, type-conversion, kettle, endianness, pdi

I need  to use Kettle/PDI community  version to  read  big  fixed  length  data  files and  do  some  ETL  stuff  on them.  During  development stage  I  faced  following  issue:

- Kettle plugin "Fixed File Input"  allows multiple  data  types with  remark they are  actually Strings or  byte arrays.
- My  input contained both:  Strings  and  byte  arrays corresponding to Little  Endian representation of long, int and short (Intel specific endian-ness). 
  Example  of  record  structure to be read:
         Column1(char:8), Column2(long:8 hex), Column3(char:2),Column4(int:4 hex).

I tried  to use "Select Values"  plugin  and  change  Binary  type  of  column to  Integer  but  such method  is  not implemented.   Finaly  I  ended with  following solution:

- I used  "User Defined Java Class"  with  code pasted  below.

As  you can see   I  used a formula  to obtain long value.

```
   public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{       
    Object[] r = getRow();

    if (r == null) {
      setOutputDone();
      return false;
    }

    // It is always safest to call createOutputRow() to ensure that your output row's Object[] is large
    // enough to handle any new fields you are creating in this step.
    r = createOutputRow(r, data.outputRowMeta.size());      

    // Get the value from an input field
    byte[] buf;
    long  longValue;

    // BAN_L - 8 bytes
    buf= get(Fields.In, "BAN").getBinary(r);      
    longValue=  ((buf[0] & 0xFFL) << 0) | ((buf[1] & 0xFFL) << 8)
                | ((buf[2] & 0xFFL) << 16) | ((buf[3] & 0xFFL) << 24)
                | ((buf[4] & 0xFFL) << 32) | ((buf[5] & 0xFFL) << 40)
                | ((buf[6] & 0xFFL) << 48) | ((buf[7] & 0xFFL) << 56);      
    get(Fields.Out, "BAN_L").setValue(r, longValue);

    //DEPOSIT_PAID_AMT -4 bytes
    buf = get(Fields.In, "DEPOSIT_PAID_AMT").getBinary(r);
    longValue=  ((buf[0] & 0xFFL) << 0) | ((buf[1] & 0xFFL) << 8)
                | ((buf[2] & 0xFFL) << 16) | ((buf[3] & 0xFFL) << 24);
    get(Fields.Out, "DEPOSIT_PAID_AMT_L").setValue(r, longValue);

    //BILL_SEQ_NO_L -2 bytes
    buf = get(Fields.In, "BILL_SEQ_NO").getBinary(r);
    longValue =  ((buf[0] & 0xFFL) << 0) | ((buf[1] & 0xFFL) << 8);
    get(Fields.Out, "BILL_SEQ_NO_L").setValue(r, longValue);    


    // Send the row on to the next step.
    putRow(data.outputRowMeta, r);

    //binaryToDecimal();

    return true;
}
```

Problem  arise  when  I  have  in one  data  extracts  8-20  binary  fields.
Is  there  any  alternative  to  this approach  so  I  can  call something like:

```
getNumberFromLE(byte [] buff, buff.length);
```

Is  there  any  other  plugin in development which can  be  used  to transform byte[]  to   Pentaho Kettle  "Number" data type? (BigNumber and Integer  are also  good).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  found following possibilities:

1) it  is  possible  to  add  additional types  to  ValueMetaInterface class:

```
org.pentaho.di.core.row.ValueMetaInterface
```

and  add  conversion functions  into

```
org.pentaho.di.core.row.ValueMeta
```

2) add code snippet implementation getNumberFromLE to "Common use" Code snippits of  "User Defined Java Class"

3) add  as  plugin  new  data types as described  in bellow  two links: 
    [Jira pluggable types](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-191)
    [GitHub pdi-valuemeta-map](https://github.com/mattyb149/pdi-valuemeta-map)
    [AddingDataTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424762/2468335)